# Inflating a new layout to replace existing one

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I load a layout in the main Activity's `onCreate()` method via a layout inflater. I would like to offer alternative layouts a user can set in my app's Settings.

Is it simply a matter of invalidating the current view and inflating the new layout in the settings code when the user makes the setting change prior to returning to the main activity? Or do I need to add if statements to the Activity's `onCreate` to inflate the set layout and therefore require the user to restart the app after changing the setting?

Thanks

Comment: post your relevant code :)

Comment: Remove current view my layout.removeallView(); and then inflate new view

Comment: I'd love to post it, AndroidLearner, but there's nothing to show as this is more of a learning question on how to inflate a new layout for an existing Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user navigates from your main activity to the preferences activity, your main activity enters `onPause()` lifecycle method and your activity goes to background. you lose reference to the main activity. After the changes are made to the shared preferences and and the user presses back button your main activity is brought to fore ground. You could add a conditional statement in `onResume()` to check Whether the user has chosen new layout.

I presume that you are invalidating a view in your activity rather than trying to refresh the entire layout of your activity (which you can do by passing a new layout to `setContentView()` in `onResume()` albeit with conditional statement to match your requirement).

Comment: I suspected onResume() is the place to do this. And yes, I'm invalidating the view. A tiny complication is that I'm dealing with fragments, but that's not a big issue. It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it in onCreate with setContentView...meaning you cant do it ad-hoc, rather you would have to finish and restart the Activity.

Using Fragments to provide your content and simply swapping them out is the better way to go.